# Type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'File' problem

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile-development

I made a form to add an image and its information in a ListView.builder(), this is the image screenshot and code:

[image]

```
class _AddNewProductState extends State<AddNewProduct> {
  String? dropdownValue = 'Fruits';
  String? productName;
  int? productPrice;

  Future<void> openMobileImagePicker() async {
    final XFile? pickedMobileImage =
        await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (pickedMobileImage != null) {
      setState(() {
        ImageFiles.mobileImage = File(pickedMobileImage.path);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  const Text(
                    'Add New Product To The Market',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 25,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                    child: Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                        boxShadow: const [
                          BoxShadow(
                            offset: Offset(0, 10),
                            blurRadius: 30,
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
                        child: Form(
                          key: UniversalKey.formKey,
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              ElevatedButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    openMobileImagePicker();
                                  });
                                },
                                child: const Text('Add Product Image'),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(
                                height: 20,
                              ),
                              Container(
                                height: 120,
                                width: 120,
                                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                  boxShadow: [
                                    BoxShadow(
                                      blurRadius: 15,
                                      color: Colors.grey,
                                    )
                                  ],
                                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                ),
                                child: CircleAvatar(
                                    backgroundImage: (ImageFiles.mobileImage !=
                                            null)
                                        ? Image.file(ImageFiles.mobileImage!,
                                                fit: BoxFit.fill)
                                            .image
                                        : null),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(
                                height: 20,
                              ),
                              TextFormField(
                                onSaved: (value) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    ProductDetails.productName = value!;
                                  });
                                },
                                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: 'Product Name',
                                    hintText: 'Add Product Name'),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(
                                height: 20,
                              ),
                              TextFormField(
                                onSaved: (value) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    ProductDetails.productPrice = value!;
                                  });
                                },
                                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: 'Product Price',
                                    hintText: 'Add Product Price'),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(
                                height: 20,
                              ),
                              DropdownButton<String>(
                                value: dropdownValue,
                                items: productCategory,
                                                               onChanged: (item) =>
                                    setState(() => dropdownValue = item),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(
                                height: 20,
                              ),
                              ElevatedButton(

                                  onPressed: () {
                                    listOfProducts.add(
                                        {
                                          'productImage' : ProductDetails.productImage,
                                          'productName' : ProductDetails.productName,
                                          'productPrice' : ProductDetails.productPrice,
                                          'productCategory' : dropdownValue,
                                        }
                                    );

                                  }


                                  ,

                                   child: const Text('Add Product!'))
                              ,
                              const SizedBox(
                                height: 20,
                              ),

                              ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {

                                setState(() {
                                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const GroceryPage(),),);
                                });
                              }, child: const Text('Go To Hompage'),),

                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When I tap 'Submit' it's supposed to add the information in a  ListView.builder() , this is the image screenshot and code:

[image]

```
class ProductsListView extends StatelessWidget {

  const ProductsListView({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemCount: fruitsList.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return ClipRect(
          child: Container(
            width: 140.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
              color: Colors.white,
              boxShadow: const [
                BoxShadow(
                  blurRadius: 10,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 10, 10, 10),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Image.file(
                    listOfProducts[index]['productImage']
                    ,
                    height: 80.0,
                    width: 90.0,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 15,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            listOfProducts[index]['productName'],
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 15.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            listOfProducts[index]['productCategory'],
                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              height: 1.5,
                              color: kDarkGrey,
                              fontSize: 12.5,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        listOfProducts[index]['productPrice'],
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const Spacer(),
                      const AddProduct(),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

But the result is:

[image]

How can I fix it? I tried many ways with no success, I don't know which part of the code causes the error?

Relative code snippets:

```
class ImageFiles {
  static File? mobileImage;
  static Uint8List? webImage;
}

class ProductDetails {
  static File? productImage;
  static String? productName;
  static String? productPrice;
}


List<Map<String, dynamic>> listOfProducts = [


];

I hope someone can help me via checking the project repo:

https://github.com/ahmloutfy/Grocery-Store.git
```

Comment: You need to check if the image file you're trying to render is null or not before rendering it. It's because the Widget where image is trying to render expected an item of type File but it got Null.

Comment: I already picked the image from emulator gallery

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no `stackTrace` provided, I'll suggest using a debugger or print statements to check the value of `mobileImage`. See where it's getting null. You can track it with the error `stackTrace` in the console.

A possible reason for the error could be the following.
You're using a static property of the `ImageFiles` class to store the image selected by the user. This property might be getting overridden.

A better approach would be to create an instance of the class `ImageFiles`, initialize it `_AddNewProductState` and pass it to the `ProductsListView` widget.

Switching from static properties.

```dart
class ImageFiles {
  final File? mobileImage;
  final Uint8List? webImage;

  ImageFiles(this.mobileImages, this.webImage);
}

class ProductDetails {
  final File? productImage;
  final String? productName;
  final String? productPrice;

  ProductDetails(this.productImage, this.productName, this.productPrice);
}
```

In `_AddNewProductState`, initialize the `ImageFile` and use that object.
For example:

```dart
class _AddNewProductState extends State<AddNewProduct> {

  /// initialising
  final ImageFiles? imageFiles = ImagesFiles();

  Future<void> openMobileImagePicker() async {
        
        // using imageFiles object
        imageFiles.mobileImage = File(pickedMobileImage.path);
    
  }
```

Now pass this `ImageFile` to any other widget like `GroceryPage` or add this in the `listOfProducts` as needed.

Comment: I tried your solution with no luck

The error in the run console is:

type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'File'

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      ProductsListView.build.<anonymous closure> (package:grocery_store/models/products_cards.dart:37:42)

it refers to this part of the code:

listOfProducts[index]['productImage']

Comment: Check where you are assigning the listOfProducts[index]. Add debugger there, see all the values.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner in programing and don't know to do this. Can you assist me with TeamViewer or AnyDesk? I spent long time with this issue.

Comment: @AhmedLoutfy you can upload your code so it's accessible to everyone, like a public GitHub repo. Then share the link and we can look into it.

Comment: Here's the repo: https://github.com/ahmloutfy/Grocery-Store.git

Answer (score 0):

1- Add a variable **productImage** in **_AddNewProductState**

```
String? productImage;
```

2- in this method **openMobileImagePicker** replace this line:

```
ImageFiles.mobileImage = File(pickedMobileImage.path);
```

with this:

```
productImage = pickedMobileImage.path;
```

3- replace this:

```
child: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: (ImageFiles.mobileImage != null)
              ? Image.file(ImageFiles.mobileImage!, fit: BoxFit.fill).image
              : null),
```

with this:

```
child: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: (productImage != null)
              ? Image.file(File(productImage), fit: BoxFit.fill).image
              : null),
```

4- replace this:

```
TextFormField(
                                onSaved: (value) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    ProductDetails.productPrice = value!;
                                  });
                                },
                                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: 'Product Price',
                                    hintText: 'Add Product Price'),
                              ),
```

with this:

```
TextFormField(
                                onSaved: (value) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    productPrice = value??"";
                                  });
                                },
                                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: 'Product Price',
                                    hintText: 'Add Product Price'),
                              ),
```

5- replace this:

```
TextFormField(
                                onSaved: (value) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    ProductDetails.productName = value!;
                                  });
                                },
                                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: 'Product Name',
                                    hintText: 'Add Product Name'),
                              ),
```

with this:

```
TextFormField(
                                onSaved: (value) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    productName = value??"";
                                  });
                                },
                                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: 'Product Name',
                                    hintText: 'Add Product Name'),
                              ),
```

6- replace this:

```
ElevatedButton(
   onPressed: () {
      listOfProducts.add({
        'productImage':ProductDetails.productImage,
        'productName' : ProductDetails.productName,
        'productPrice' : ProductDetails.productPrice,
        'productCategory' : dropdownValue,
        });

                },
  child: const Text('Add Product!'))
```

with this:

```
ElevatedButton(
       onPressed: () {
          listOfProducts.add({
            'productImage':productImage,
            'productName' : productName,
            'productPrice' : productPrice,
            'productCategory' : dropdownValue,
            });
    
                    },
      child: const Text('Add Product!'))
```